# Parametrization of a curve with a specific orientation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the curve $x^2+z^2=1$ with $y=1$ and i was asked to find a parametrization positively oriented with regard to the versor $\vec j$.

Now... I'm not sure of what this means, i have found the parametrization $x=\cos \theta ,\ \ y=1, \ \ z=\sin \theta $ but i don't know if it has the correct orientation and what i should do to find out.

Any help will be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From right-hand law, when you turn about $y-$axis counter-clockwise, then the direction of your thumb will be the positive $y-$axis, that's $\vec{j}$. So your parametrization isn't positively!

Comment: Oh right! So i guess the correct parametrization will be $r(\theta)=(sin\ \theta, 1, cos\ \theta)$ isn't it? Thanks for the hint, i forgot to see it like this.

Comment: Yes! it is.....

Answer (score 0):

This curve is a circle around the $y$ axis. Essentially, if you are moving around the curve, you want the direction given by the right hand rule as positive to match the positive $y$ direction. This means you should select counter clockwise for your curve, i.e. the usual way of parametrizing a circle 
$$
r(t)=(\cos t,1,\sin t)
$$